# Is there any way to import the data from s3 to mssql

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have hadoop cluster running on `amazon EMR` which process some data and write the output to `s3`. Now, I want to import that data in `mssql`. Is there any open source connector for that ? Or i have to manually download the data, change the default seperator '\001' to ',' and then import data in `mssql`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way.

Use below config in map reduce to write output , as delimiter

job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", ",");

The best way is to keep processed data in s3. You can  CSV to s3. The write a php/java/shell to download data from s3 and load it to mssql.

You can use s3download directory to download the processed data and then use **bulk insert** to load the csv file to mssql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Sqoop for this use case.
Apache Sqoop supports importing from and exporting to mssql.

The following article explains how to install Sqoop in EMR
http://blog.kylemulka.com/2012/04/how-to-install-sqoop-on-amazon-elastic-map-reduce-emr/

Please refer to Sqoop user guide.
http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html